# How to fix 'No module named cv2' in AWS EC2 Linux, imports from Command Line

Tags: python, opencv, amazon-ec2

I am deploying a web application onto an AWS EC2 instance, and I'm getting an error. The logs indicate that I do not have cv2 installed.
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'`

However, if I ssh into my instance, and run python from the shell I can import no problem.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-w3BN9pMAhkiDM40fODCPdjvU1Nx71UT?usp=sharing

I have already installed opencv onto the Linux server and checked that it is available for import.

From my application.py file

```
import cv2

File "/opt/python/current/app/localize.py", line 9, in
```

but from the command line:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'4.1.0'
```

I expected the import to work since it works from the command line.

Comment: have you built opencv from source or just installed binaries?

Comment: @enoted I installed using ` sudo pip install opencv-python`

Comment: try to build it from source. Here is a great tutorial.
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/28/ubuntu-18-04-how-to-install-opencv/

Comment: What is most likely happening is that the version of Python that is being called by your web application and what you are invoking in the Terminal are not the same Python version.  Is there a way for you to determine which Python executable is being run on the EC2 instance when you run the application as opposed to what you're running in the terminal? For example, in the terminal when you SSH in,  you can type in `which python` to figure out which version you're using.  When you did `pip install`, it used `pip` and thus Python for that specific version.

Comment: When you say `web application` do you mean a flask app or django app or just a barebones project with a wsgi script? In any case, how are you deploying it? Over apache2 or nginx? If you're using any of these two you have point the app to the appropriate virtualenv in the web server's config file.

Comment: @rayryeng you were right that I was running two separate python versions. I installed the correct version, but (surprisingly) still no dice. Same import error.

Comment: And after you installed the correct version, did you install OpenCV for that version?

Comment: @rayryeng yes, I installed the python 3 versions. I am wondering if I need to activate a virtual env

Comment: I would. It avoids problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your python package is available for the root/admin user but not accessible for the user trying to run the code?
If you can import that module in your EC2, then it is installed, but more importantly for which user it is installed, and for which version.
First try :
chmod 755 on all directories in python path for your default python and see if it works.(This will provide permissions for all import libraries in Python)
If your script is running Python3.7 and Default is Python2.7 then you might have to do --
sudo pip3 install opencv-python

the way to check the version defaults is:

```
which python ---Will provide default python path and version

which pip ---- Will Provide default PIP details
```

Answer (score 1):

As @rayryeng suggested, I'm running Python 3.x from Elastic Beanstalk, and Python 2.x from command line. I fixed it by installing the correct version of cv2 for Python 3 and including the following before my import:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages')
```

Comment: Nice job in figuring it out. Contrary to what other people have said, you obviously didn't have to rebuild from source.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cd 
wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.2.0.zip
virtualenv project
source project/bin/activate
pip install numpy
mkdir local
unzip opencv-3.2.0.zip
cd opencv-3.2.0
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=NO -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON -D BUILD_opencv_python2=ON -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/local ~/opencv-3.2.0
make
make install
cp ~/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so ~/project/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Read more from here: [Source](https://gist.github.com/joseph-zhong/372a47bb618111dcd2c81008d00357b2)